# Edit .dtsx file without the SSIS project

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We got a SSIS maintenance plan package in our client's server which does the database backups (Back Up Database Task). We need to export this package to a new database server and need to change the backup locations and sql serer server configurations in the package.

The problem is we do not have the actual SSIS project but the .dtsx file.It's possible to do the changes just by using .dtsx file design by opening it on SQL Server Data Tools but does it require to do a build and then import the file in to stored packages?

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience, take a backup of the file, open the file in notepad or notepad++ and edit the locations. it is that simple. And should test first in UAT or PreProd :)

Comment: that is kind of my thing on daily basis. even password protected packages can be modified using any text editor.